# Points vs. Pixels and Saving as .png

Tags: print-design, resolution

I am a beginner level graphic designer using primarily GIMP, but getting into PScc. For now, I'm creating primarily for print on demand products (you know the stuff), but I'm working at learning how to design logos as well.

Here's my question:

It seems as if for designing logos in PScc my best option is to choose points and save the layers as shapes so they are later scalable. Does this also mean I don't have to worry about creating at a higher level of dpi? For example in GIMP, I always set the ppi parameter to about 300 - just to make sure the print quality would be decent.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: Actually, for logos you want to use a vector application - Illustrator, Inkscape, Xara, etc. Photoshop isn't the best tool for "logos".

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is created as a vector shape in Photoshop is scalable as long as it remains a vector shape. But you have to keep in mind that it will NOT be a vector shape if you make the layer a Smart Object or if you place the PSD into any other application. In both cases, the result will be rasterized and will look pixelated if scaled up.

Be sure to `Save As` a copy of your PSD as a Photoshop PDF and place the PDF instead.

A good practice is to make your Photoshop original as large as you're likely to need -- you will generally be safe if you use a Print document preset.

A much better practice if you're going to be creating logos is to learn how to use Adobe Illustrator and make them there.